Почему featuretools отдает только фичи по датам
Есть DataFrame, состоящий из столбцов
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------            --------------  -----  
 0   index             114 non-null    int64  
 1   version           114 non-null    object 
 2   format            114 non-null    object 
 3   metadata          114 non-null    object 
 4   request_date      114 non-null    object 
 5   response_date     33 non-null     object 
 6   request_age_days  114 non-null    int64  
 7   request_timeslot  114 non-null    object 
 8   request_code      33 non-null     float64
 9   request_type      33 non-null     object 
 10  partner_code      114 non-null    object 
 11  partner_type      114 non-null    object 
 13  request_amount    105 non-null    float64
 14  request_currency  110 non-null    object 
 15  is_pos            0 non-null      float64

По этому набору данных создаю EntitySet
es = ft.EntitySet(id='req_inf')
es = es.add_dataframe(
    dataframe_name='requests',
    dataframe=df,
    index='index',
    time_index='request_date'
)

Далее пытаюсь нагенерить фичей
features = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_dataframe_name='requests',
    max_depth=4, # Увеличьте глубину поиска до 4 уровней
    max_features=5000, # Увеличьте максимальное количество фич до 5000
)

но в итоге выделяется только день, месяц, год дат и больше ничего. Как это исправить или подскажите где я что-то делаю не так? Пробовал явно указывать trans_primitives и agg_primitives. А также пробовал явно указывать logical_types при добавлении DataFrame и ничего не помогает.
Пример получаемого ответа:
Index(['version', 'format', 'request_age_days', 'request_timeslot',
       'request_code', 'request_type', 'partner_code', 'partner_type',
       'request_amount', 'request_currency', 'DAY(request_date)',
       'DAY(response_date)', 'MONTH(request_date)', 'MONTH(response_date)',
       'WEEKDAY(request_date)', 'WEEKDAY(response_date)', 'YEAR(request_date)',
       'YEAR(response_date)'],
      dtype='object')

